# Create silhoutte of an image using PIL

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I have an image like [this](http://s11.postimg.org/5yk2vjfdr/logo1.png) that I'm trying to create a dark silhouette of, such as [this](http://s7.postimg.org/wnppfmxsr/logo_glow1.png).

I've tried using image.filter(ImageFilter.BLUR) with varying radii but the intensity gets reduced a lot. Is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

FYI your first link doesn't work. If by intensity you mean darkness of the color you might want to try using ImageFilter.UnsharpMask. That might mix less of what I assume to be a white background into the middle of the logo while giving the soft edges you are looking for.